# Find a simple representation for a number with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am struggling to simplify the following term with `sympy`

(latex) $\sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay0YU.png){8+3\sqrt{21}}+\sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay0YU.png){8-3\sqrt{21}}$

```py
from sympy import (
    init_printing,
    sqrt,
    cbrt,
    nsimplify,
    simplify,
)

init_printing(use_unicode=True)

value_plus = cbrt(8 + 3 * sqrt(21))
value_minus = cbrt(8 - 3 * sqrt(21))

value_both = value_plus + value_minus
```

Here, I have separeted the expression in two parts `value_plus` and `value_minus`, respectively.

For the first part, I get a desired result

```
nsimplify(value_plus)
```

which is $1/2+\sqrt{21}/2$ as can be seen in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cuberoot(8%2B3sqrt(21))).

However, for the second part intead of a desired result ($1/2-\sqrt{21}/2$) as can be seen in [wolfram aplha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cuberoot(8-3sqrt(21))) as well, under alternate form

```
nsimplify(value_minus)
```

I end up with a complex representation, which is also correct, but not exactly what I want to get.

And thus, I do not get the expected result, which is 1.

```
value_both = value_plus + value_minus
```

as can be seen on the screenshot.
So my questions are,

1. how to force other representations of a number?
2. how to restrict the representation to real numbers only?

[image: Screenshot of a jupiter notebook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `cbrt` you can use [real_root](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#real-root):

```
value_plus = real_root(8 + 3 * sqrt(21), 3)
value_minus = real_root(8 - 3 * sqrt(21), 3)

value_both = value_plus + value_minus

print(nsimplify(value_plus))
print(nsimplify(value_minus))
print(nsimplify(value_both))
```

Output will be:

```
1/2 + sqrt(21)/2
1/2 - sqrt(21)/2
1
```